# JGit: GPG to commit files without passing passphrase nor using console input?

Tags: java, gnupg, jgit, gpg-signature

I am trying to use gpg to commit to git, I have my username and token already being used and it works without any passphrase using ssh but not for gpg!

I am coming across below error

```
org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPException: missing credentials provider
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.internal.BouncyCastleGpgKeyPassphrasePrompt.getPassphrase(BouncyCastleGpgKeyPassphrasePrompt.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.internal.BouncyCastleGpgKeyLocator.findSecretKeyForKeyBoxPublicKey(BouncyCastleGpgKeyLocator.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.internal.BouncyCastleGpgKeyLocator.findSecretKey(BouncyCastleGpgKeyLocator.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.internal.BouncyCastleGpgSigner.locateSigningKey(BouncyCastleGpgSigner.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.internal.BouncyCastleGpgSigner.sign(BouncyCastleGpgSigner.java:129)
    ... 33 common frames omitted
```

I want to understand these things:

1. What credentials/Configuration is expected from jgit to use GPG?
2. How can we send passphrase and how to make sure cached gpg passphrase is used?

I have tried below things:

1. Added credentials to at `.netrc` machine, username and password
2. Enabled `command.setSign(true)`
3. Added SigningKey `command.setSigningKey("KEY")`

I have these setting:

`.netrc`

```
machine github.com
login <login>
password <personal_token>
```

`.zshrc`

```
# GPG
export GPG_TTY=`tty`
```

`.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`

```
default-cache-ttl 28880
write-env-file /Users/[your user]/.gnupg/gpg-agent-info
pinentry-program /usr/local/MacGPG2/libexec/pinentry-mac.app/Contents/MacOS/pinentry-mac
```

`gpg.conf`

```
auto-key-retrieve
no-emit-version
default-key <key>
use-agent
no-tty
```